# Distance matrix for custom distance

Tags: python, scipy, distance-matrix

From what I understand, the scipy function [scipy.spatial.distance_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html) returns the Minkowski distance for any pair of vectors from the provided matrices of vectors. Is there a way to get the same result for a different distance? Something that would look like `distance_matrix(X, Y, distance_function)` ?

I assume that scipy does some sort of optimization under the hood. Since I am dealing with very large vectors, I would rather not lose the benefit of these optimizations by implementing my own distance_matrix function.

Comment: The documentation says it returns "the matrix of all pair-wise distances", where did you read that it returns the Minkowski distance?

Comment: take a look at this page, it may be helpful https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

Comment: @Cristian From the documentation: "p : float, 1 <= p <= infinity

    Which Minkowski p-norm to use."

Comment: Oh sure, mmh well I'm not sure there is such a function "distance_matrix(X, Y, distance_function)" but something you can do is to rewrite your custom distance in function of existing distances already present in scipy.

Comment: You probably do not want `distance_matrix` then (which looks like a helper-function), but `pdist/cdist` (which support own metrics), potentially followed by `squareform`. Yes, some doc-reading is needed to grasp the various in- and output assumptions in these methods. [distance_matrix](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4ffff4b55702f38006ab69641b794ef5f7f1a84a/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py#L945) is hardcoded for minkowski.

Comment: From what I understand of the pdist documentation, I can only choose a distance from a list of distances. "The distance function can be ‘braycurtis’, ‘canberra’, ‘chebyshev’, ‘cityblock’, ‘correlation’, ‘cosine’, ‘dice’, ‘euclidean’, ‘hamming’, ‘jaccard’, ‘jensenshannon’, ‘kulsinski’, ‘mahalanobis’, ‘matching’, ‘minkowski’, ‘rogerstanimoto’, ‘russellrao’, ‘seuclidean’, ‘sokalmichener’, ‘sokalsneath’, ‘sqeuclidean’, ‘yule’."

Answer (score 0):

### It is quite straight forward to implement it yourself

Also the performance will very likely be better than the distance functions already implemented in scipy.

Most of the distance functions are applying one function on all pairs and sum them up eg. `(A_ik-B_jk)**n` for Minkowski distance and at the end there is some other function applied eg. `acc**(1/n)`.

**Template function**

You don't have to change anything here to implement various distance functions.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def gen_cust_dist_func(kernel_inner,kernel_outer,parallel=True):

    kernel_inner_nb=nb.njit(kernel_inner,fastmath=True,inline='always')
    kernel_outer_nb=nb.njit(kernel_outer,fastmath=True,inline='always')

    def cust_dot_T(A,B):
        assert B.shape[1]==A.shape[1]

        out=np.empty((A.shape[0],B.shape[0]),dtype=A.dtype)
        for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
            for j in range(B.shape[0]):
                acc=0
                for k in range(A.shape[1]):
                    acc+=kernel_inner_nb(A[i,k],B[j,k])
                out[i,j]=kernel_outer_nb(acc)
        return out

    if parallel==True:
        return nb.njit(cust_dot_T,fastmath=True,parallel=True)
    else:
        return nb.njit(cust_dot_T,fastmath=True,parallel=False)
```

**Examples and Timings**

```
#Implement for example a Minkowski distance and euclidian distance
#Minkowski distance p=20
inner=lambda A,B:(A-B)**20
outer=lambda acc:acc**(1./20)
my_minkowski_dist=gen_cust_dist_func(inner,outer,parallel=True)

#Euclidian distance
inner=lambda A,B:(A-B)**2
outer=lambda acc:np.sqrt(acc)
my_euclidian_dist=gen_cust_dist_func(inner,outer,parallel=True)

from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

A=np.random.rand(1000,50)
B=np.random.rand(1000,50)

#Minkowski p=20
%timeit res_1=cdist(A,B,'m',p=20)
#1.44 s ± 8.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_2=my_minkowski_dist(A,B)
#10.8 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
res_1=cdist(A,B,'m',p=20)
res_2=my_minkowski_dist(A,B)
print(np.allclose(res_1,res_2))
#True

#Euclidian
%timeit res_1=cdist(A,B,'euclidean')
#39.3 ms ± 307 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit res_2=my_euclidian_dist(A,B)
#3.61 ms ± 22.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
res_1=res_1=cdist(A,B,'euclidean')
res_2=my_euclidian_dist(A,B)
print(np.allclose(res_1,res_2))
#True
```