# Implementing custom matrix multiplication-like operations in numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to implement an operation on two matrices that is similar to matrix multiplication in that it each element of the resulting matrix is a function of the `i`th row of the first matrix and the `j`th column of the second matrix.
I would like to be able to do this using numpy and/or pandas using vectorized computations.

In other words:
How do I implemenent `$A \bigotimes B = C$`
where `$C_{ij} = sum_k f(a_{ik}, b_{kj})$` in numpy and/or pandas?

Comment: show a sample of your input and output data [mcve]

Comment: Do you have a specific function in mind, or is this supposed to be a 'plug-your-function-in' case?  To get speed that's anything like `dot`, you'll need to use compiled code, such as with `numba` or `cython`.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/59256512/4045774 is an example for np.dot(A,B.T). Because of the memory alignment it may make sense to use this function and create a real transpose of  B beforehand (np.copy(B.T))